# How do I copy (standard) ctypes bindings?

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I'm using ctypes bindings like the following. Is it possible to make a private copy of `PyCapsule_New` and other bindings instead of modifying global `ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_New`? Do I `copy.deepcopy(...)` it or is there another method?

```py
PyCapsule_New = ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_New
PyCapsule_New.restype = ctypes.py_object
PyCapsule_New.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_void_p)

PyCapsule_GetPointer = ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer
PyCapsule_GetPointer.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
PyCapsule_GetPointer.argtypes = (ctypes.py_object, ctypes.c_char_p)
```

Answer (score 0):

From experimentation, this is equivalent (same DLL handle, different instance of wrapper).

```
>>> import ctypes,sys
>>> ctypes.pythonapi
<PyDLL 'python dll', handle 5f6b0000 at 0x182add5f0b8>
>>> ctypes.PyDLL(f'python{sys.version_info.major}{sys.version_info.minor}')
<PyDLL 'python36', handle 5f6b0000 at 0x182add43a20>
```

You can similarly use `WinDLL` and 'CDLL' instead of the global `winapi` and `cdll`, respectively.